# C# nested structures marshaling

Tags: c#, interop, marshalling

Currently I'm woking on a dll written in C# which exports methods (via UnmanagedExports NuGet package) and is supposed to be used by unmanaged application.

Let's assume we have the following unmanaged structure passed to the managed dll:

```
struct RecordData {
     int x, y;
     char description[64];
}
```

Then to work with it I need to create it's C# counterpart which should be like that:

```
struct RecordData {
    public int x, y;
    [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.ByValTStr, SizeConst=64)]
    public string description;
}
```

and then pass to through IntPtr argument.

Everything is clear so far. But what if I have another one struct which contains pointer to the first one?

Unmanaged part:

```
struct Record {
    char name[64];
    RecordData* data;
    int data_len;
};
```

Here **data** points to somewhere in unmanaged heap and **data_len** is array's length and the struct also is passed from unmanaged to managed code.

How do I perform marshaling in this case? Just **RecordData*** member won't work as it's managed data type (due to **string** member). 
In C# part, I can declare **data** member as **IntPtr**, of course, and create an array using **Marshal.PtrToStructure**, but then I will have to create some additional data structures to use the data retrieved because **IntPtr** doesn't make much sense besides frontier interface functions.

**The question is**: is it possible to set marshaling parameters so that unmanaged **RecordData* data** pointer be marshaled to managed array of it's managed counterparts automatically? Or using **IntPtr** is the only solution?

What I would like to have is a C# Record struct with RecordData array, like this:

```
struct Record {
    [some marshaling params]
    public string name;
    [...]
    public RecordData [] data;
    int data_len; //redundant?
};
```

with data array not embedded in the struct itself, but passed from unmanaged code as a pointer to some buffer.

**EDIT**: is creating a custom marshaler a right way of doing what I want?

Comment: Sure, IntPtr and Marshal.PtrToStructure gets the job done.  Just keep in mind that your structure declaration only has to match the C declaration, you can store the data any way you like.  Do keep your eye on the ball, the Pinvoke marshaller can't handle declarations like this because it cannot know what should be done with the memory allocated for RecordData*.  If it needs to be released to avoid a memory leak then you have a Big Problem.

Comment: May I suggest C++/CLI...

Comment: Customer wants C#...